# Execute command if file exists - Unix

Tags: shell

I am using the below command to check for .gz files and un-compress it if any but i am getting error...

Can you please let me know if the below script is correct or not?

```
if [-s /logs/*.gz]
then
*.gz|gunzip
fi
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: No, it is not correct. There are *many* problems with that snippet of code. (Spacing around `[` and `]` in the `if` line. You cannot expand a glob in a `[`/`test` like that and get a meaningful answer. You cannot use a bare glob like that in a pipeline.)

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
gunzip *.gz
```

or possibly

```
gunzip /logs/*.gz
```

should do what you want. If no files match the wildcard, you will get a harmless error message.

You need a space after `[` and before `]`, and `-s` will not do what you want; and of course, `*.gz` is not a command whose output can be piped to `gunzip`.